# Alternative for body parser package

Tags: node.js, express

Suggest an alternative for solving body parser deprecated issue. Best alternative package for body parser.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

Answer (score 0):

You can surely use: 
`express.urlencoded({ extended: true })`
Reference: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html